# Get position of joints in armature using Python

Tags: scripting, armature, makehuman

First of all, I'm using :

- MakeHuman 1.2.0a3
- Blender 2.7
- MH Community Plugin

I've created a pretty generic model in MakeHuman with a "Game Engine" rig and I've imported it in Blender using the community plugin.

In this image, you see there are some spheres that seems to be joints between different bones. I need to get the coordinates of these joints using scripts (in Python, obviously) in order to do some operations in MatLab. I've searched the web, but between the different API versions of Blender's scripting and my lack of knowledge of Blender, I wasn't able to figure out how to do it.

Let's say, in my example below, that the selected joint is named "knee_l", how would I retrieve its coordinates using Python?

[image: MakeHuman model with armature]

Comment: Have you found a solution to your question?